# Show Currency in PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel, currency

I want to format my cells with currency, but I cannot find a way to make It happen. Respectively I'm note really sure where I have to put the code to show the currency behind the values.

I've tried several solutions from the forum but nothing worked.

```
require_once "Classes/PHPExcel.php";
    $tmpfname = "test.xlsx";
    $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
    $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
    $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
    $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();




    echo "<table>";
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
         echo "<tr><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "</td><td>";
         echo $worksheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue();
         echo "</td><tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cells are already formatted use `getFormattedValue` instead of `getValue` when you retrieve them.

```
echo $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getFormattedValue();
echo "</td><td>";
echo $worksheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getFormattedValue();
```

If you want to format the raw values from the spreadsheet using your existing code then the PHP [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function is what you are looking for (in the example below I told it to use 2 decimal places which you may of course change).

```
echo number_format($worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getFormattedValue(),2);
echo "</td><td>";
echo number_format($worksheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getFormattedValue(),2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to work but instead of the "€" sign there appears just "â‚¬". Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like the encoding of your document is not correct. Most likely you want it to be UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks!! That was the problem. Maybe you could help me with another question. How can I just read specific cells from my excel sheet? For example if I just wan to read A3 - A7.

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. [Here's how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/379718), then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!

Comment: To your other question see the section titled **Retrieving a range of cell values to an array** in the [documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/accessing-cells/).